# SBT Cannot find Jar from Local Maven Repository

Tags: maven, sbt

I registered a jar file in my local maven repo as follows

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=./hadoop-vertica.jar -DgroupId="com.hp" -DartifactId="mapred" -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then I successfully used it in a maven pom.xml java project as follows

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hp</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapred</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Next I need to write a scala project and I need to use this Jar. So in my SBT file I use this jar as follows

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.hp" % "mapred" % "1.0.0" % "provided"
)
```

However SBT throws an error saying

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.hp#mapred;1.0.0: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:291)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:188)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:165)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:132)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it myself. Posting the answer here

You need to add the local maven repo in sbt built.sbt file as follows

```
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"
```

Comment: suggest marking it as correct or deleting both answer and question.

Comment: The correct way is `resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal`.